# How to set a paragraph, button and text box in a same row?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have been trying to place subscribe button, paragraph, and text box in the same row. I'm using React Storybook. Also, I wanna add background colors to the same row inside my Scss file.
Here's the image attached for reference.
[image]

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.scss";

function Footer() {
  return (
    <div className="main-footer">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {/*Column 1 */}
          <div className="col">
            <h1>News Letter</h1>
            <p>Freebies,news & promos directly in your inbox.</p>
          </div>
          {/*Column 2 */}
          <div className="col">
            <label className="subscribe">
              <input
                type="text"
                value=" enter your email"
                placeholder="enter your email"
              />
            </label>
            <input type="button" value="Subscribe" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

Answer (score 0):

`p` tag is a block-level element which occupies the whole width. Change its `display` property to `inline`

Answer (score 0):

Have a parent div then in CSS sheet:

```css
div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `<p>` and `<h1>` tags are the block-level element which means they will take up 100% of width and will force a line break.

According to your requirement, you can apply display flex property to row div which can have multiple columns to that div.

We require align-self of col-2 to the center because margin-top and margin-bottom of 1em are applied to `p` tag as default.

To avoid such a problem we can apply `margin: 0;` to our universal select which is going to apply to every element.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col-2 { 
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <h1>News Letter</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <p>Freebies,news & promos directly in your inbox.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-2">
        <label class="subscribe">
              <input
                type="text"
                value=" enter your email"
                placeholder="enter your email"
              />
            </label>
        <input type="button" value="Subscribe" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```